# jstl display nesting object data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, jstl

I am working with jsp, hibernate, and spring.

My problem is that I have an object named "carsearchlist" and within carsearchlist, I have another two objects named user and car. For some reason this foreach loop will not work.

```
    <c:forEach var="csl" items="${carsearchlist}">
     ${csl.id}
         <c:forEach var="name" items="${csl.user}">
               ${name.first} 
         </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```

My data is showing the the HQL editor as what's shown in the screen shot here:

http://i244.photobucket.com/albums/gg5/robasc/ScreenShot2013-02-12at120841AM_zpsdb5449b4.png

Also here is my mapping for CarSearchList:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 9, 2013 8:14:19 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.usedcarsearch.domain.CarSearchList" table="Car_Search_List">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="car" class="com.usedcarsearch.domain.Car" fetch="select">
        <column name="fkCarId" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="user" class="com.usedcarsearch.domain.User" fetch="select">
        <column name="fkUserId" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Any help at all would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: do you have some errors in browser when open page?

Comment: I would suspect lazy loading issue. Look at log for LazyInitializationException.

Comment: You were right on the money. I turned off lazy loading and it worked like a champ. So what would I have to do in order to use lazy loading? I would have to say, in some cases this may come in handy. I would also like to thank JB for pointing out that my syntax was wrong. I started out using it the way JB done it but getting caught up in the lazy loading issue threw me off. I guess getting in a hurry and not reading the stack trace is really stupid on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty would be to set lazy attribute to false.
Note that this may cause performance issues.
The common practice to solve this is to use “Open Session In View Filter”. 
This blog post can help
http://sourabhissourabh.blogspot.com/2008/03/what-is-opensessioninviewfilter-and-how.html

The downside of this approach is that setting value to carsearchlist, user or car will be persisted to the database. So you have to be careful with that.

Answer (score 3):

The `CarSearchList` instance has a field of type `User`, and another field of type `Car`. And your code is trying to iterate, with `forEach`,  on `CarSearchList.user`. But `user` is not a collection or an array. It's a simple object. There's nothing to iterate on.

Moreover, the User class doesn't sem to have any `name` property. It has a 'first' property and a last property, but these are directly in the User, and not in a `Name` sub-object.

So you just need

```
<c:forEach var="csl" items="${carsearchlist}">
     ${csl.id}
     ${csl.user.first} 
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help JB and Haim. Very much appreciated